# Case insensitive search in std::map using std::find

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stdmap

I need to **find the string form the vector list through case insensitive comparison**. Is there is some easy solution for it without using Boost?

My code I have written for case sensitive search is:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it;
if (map.end() != (it = map.find(mKey)))
    // if word matches
```

Suggested by one answer I have used `find_if` and got the following exception. It is giving following error at particular value

```
 my_map1["$$HYPHEN{{a"] = "-";
```

[image]

Code tried using `lexicographical_compare`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map1;
std::map<std::string,
         std::string,
         bool(*)(const std::string&, const std::string&)>
     my_map_temp(case_insensitive_string_cmp);
my_map_temp["$$HYPHEN--a"] = "foo";
my_map_temp["$$HYPHEN{{a"] = "foo1";
while (my_map_temp.end() !=  my_map_temp.find("$$HYPHEn--a"))
    {
       std::cout << my_map_temp["hellOOOO"] << std::endl;
    }
```

But in this case how can I copy `map1` values to `my_map_temp`?

Comment: The title says vectors, but the body says map. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

`std::map::find` relies on the internal ordering of the map. If you want to use this method to do a search, then you would need to build your map with a case-insensitive comparison function, that is to say, a map that is case insensitive WRT keys.

This can easily be done by leveraging the [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) algorithm, using it with a case-insensitive element comparison:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool case_insensitive_cmp(char lhs, char rhs)
{
  return std::toupper(lhs) < std::toupper(rhs);
}

bool case_insensitive_string_cmp(const std::string& lhs, 
                                 const std::string& rhs)
{
  return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), 
                                      lhs.end(),
                                      rhs.begin(),
                                      rhs.end(),
                                      case_insensitive_cmp);
}
```

then, create the map using the case-insensitive string comparison function:

```
std::map<std::string, 
         std::string, 
         bool(*)(const std::string&, const std::string&)> 
     my_map(case_insensitive_string_cmp);

my_map["Helloooo"] = "foo";
my_map["HELLOOOO"] = "bar";
std::cout << my_map["hellOOOO"] << std::endl;
```

[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/EJax7m).

If you want your map to have the standard, case sensitive behaviour but want to perform a case-insensitive search, then you need to use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a suitable predicate. But here you lose the advantage of the map's O(logN) look-up.

Here is a working example of a case-insensitive search in a standard map. It would be much less verbose in C++11:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool case_insensitive_eq(const char& lhs, const char& rhs)
{
    return std::toupper(lhs) == std::toupper(rhs);
}

bool case_insensitive_string_eq(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
{
  return std::equal(lhs.begin(), 
                    lhs.end(),
                    rhs.begin(),
                    case_insensitive_eq);
}

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> StringMap;

struct case_insensitive_key_eq
{
  case_insensitive_key_eq(const std::string& key) : key_(key) {}

  bool operator()(StringMap::value_type item) const
  {
    return case_insensitive_string_eq(item.first, key_);
  }
  std::string key_;
};

int main()
{
  StringMap my_map;

  my_map["Helloooo"] = "foo";
  StringMap::iterator it = std::find_if(my_map.begin(), 
                                        my_map.end(), 
                                        case_insensitive_key_eq("HeLlOOoo"));
  if (it != my_map.end())
  {
    std::cout << "Found element " << it->second << std::endl;
  } else
  {
    std::cout << "element not found\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: i am very new to vectors can you add full code for me.

Comment: now what output should come from this code `std::cout << my_map["hellOOOO"] << std::endl;`?

Comment: @HeenaGoyal It should be `"bar"`, because the map is now case-insensitive.

Comment: If for some reason he only sometimes wants case-insensitive search, then the custom comparator would not be the way to go.  You could then use `std::find_if(my_map.begin(), my_map.end(), case_insensitive_string_cmp)`, but obviously you lose the O(logN) search.

Comment: @GuyGreer Agreed. I added some explanations about that.

Comment: i have written following code `if (map.end() != (it = my_map.find(mKey)))`i am getting following error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @HeenaGoyal Your maps could be of different types, in which case the iterators are incompatible. See this working example: http://ideone.com/EJax7m

Comment: @HeenaGoyal You can't compare iterators to different maps, you have an iterator to `map` and another to `my_map`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: thanks for so accrate code. but it works well when `my_map` contains only one value but when i add multiple value like ` my_map1["Helloooo"] = "foo";
  my_map1["Helloooo1"] = "fooe";  StringMap::iterator it1 = std::find_if(my_map1.begin(), my_map1.end(), case_insensitive_key_eq("HeLlOOoo1"));` it is giving exception at `findif`

Comment: @HeenaGoyal OK, I will test it later.

Comment: @juanchopanza but it is working with your array but it doesnt work with my array it is of same type but contains item in thousands. it exactly gave the error i have added in my question please see that.

Comment: @juanchopanza and moreover if use lexicographical_compare then how to get its iterator

Comment: @HeenaGoyal `lexicographical_compare` returns a `bool`, there is no need to get the iterator. Maybe you should post some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @juanchopanza: is that something diffrent if their is some special charater like `{{` or anything else?

Comment: @HeenaGoyal If you have some special character that cannot fit into `unsigned char`, and is not `EOF`, then `std::toupper` fails. Are you using a special, non-ASCII character set?

Comment: yes i am using and added some code and my question please help me @juanchopanza

Comment: @HeenaGoyal First you ask about problems with the `find_if` solution, then you post code using `std::map::find`. This really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @juanchopanza i have tried with both of the solutions. as you are saying `find_if` not work for special characters. i have shown problem wioth both type of solution. if i use `find_if` then it gives exception as shown above and `lexicographical_compare` works fine but i need to copy content of different type of vectors.